# Object rotation in time in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to write a script in Maya that will rotate object by some degrees in one second, like there is in After Effects.

Any segestions?

Comment: Did you already try to code something?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you have a library of command you can call by :

```
from maya import cmds
```

you have also the native language which is called MEl, and another python library call pymel.

Don't hesitate in the script editor to tick : "echo all command" to see command triggered by what you are doing inside maya. You should see "setAttr" used to rotate. Im letting you explore taht as stackoverflow is not on demand scripting service :]